# How can I multiply a value then multiply that number by ten, then divide the result by three, and convert the result to a percentage?

Tags: html, css

How can I multiply a value then multiply that number by ten, then divide the result by three, and convert the result to a percentage? I've tried doing this:

```css
.bar {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  --widthB: calc(300 / 400);
  --widthC: calc(var(--widthB)*10);
  --widthA: calc(var(--widthC) / 3);
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>141k</h1>
  <div class="percentage-bar">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="red">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `widthA`?

Comment: I want to divide everything by 3 then transform it into a percentage

Comment: ask your question differently by telling us what is your end goal. I am pretty sure there is an easier way to achieve your goal that you are not describing here

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to set the width of `.red` to a percent, based on the value calculated in `--widthA`, which can be done thusly:

```html
<center>
    <h1>141k</h1>
    <div class="percentage-bar">
     <div class="bar">
      <div class="red">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </center>
<style>
.bar {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  --widthB: calc(300/400);
  --widthC: calc(var(--widthB)*10);
  --widthA: calc(var(--widthC) / 3);
  width: calc(var(--widthB) * 1%);
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, there's only 1 problem, 300/400 was a fraction
and I wanted it so that when I change 300 to another number like 24 it'll change the width according to the width of .bar. Right now the width of .bar is 33.333%.
Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: If you want to know what the goal is, it's a bar that shows how close I am to 141 thousand dollars. Right now I have 300$ out of 141,000$ and I want to transform 300/141000 to a percentage then make that number the width

Comment: .2% is too small to really render on a 300px width bar. it'd be less than 1px

Comment: I'll make the bar bigger and even if it won't show it still shows that I haven't even accomplished 1%

Comment: I fixed it, you put times 10 by accident not times 100